# Linear regression where explanatory variable of 0 has no meaning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I want to build a predictive model, where given a few numeric explanatory variable `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, it would predict a boolean response variable `r1`. I see a relationship between `n1` and `r1`. As `n1` goes up, the probability of `r1` being true also goes up. For example, say the following is a representative subset of my training data (ignoring the other explanatory variables `n2` and `n3`).

```
n1     r1
 1  False 
10  False
25  False
30  False
37   True
46   True
48  False
52  False
55   True
57  False
60   True
62  False
70   True
80   True
90   True
99   True
```

It seems like it'd make sense to perform logistic regression to build the predictive model, with `n1` as the explanatory variable and `r1` as the response variable. `n1` could be a useful predictor - as it goes up from 1 to 99, the probability of `r1` being true increases.

The problem is that out of my dataset, `n1` of 0 does not follow the same relationship. If my model is valid, then `n1` of 0 should be a strong indication that `r1` is False. As it turns out from the training data, `n1` of 0 has no predictive power over `r1`. For example, say `n1` is a measurement of some kind of rate. `n1` being 0 could indicate an absence of this measurement.

```
n1     r1
 0  False 
 0   True
 0  False
 0   True
 0  False
 0   True
```

What is best way to approach this? I feel like just throwing `n1` into logistic regression is not a good idea.

One way is to add a new categorical variable - `valid_n1`, where it is True if `n1` is greater than 0, and False otherwise. I could add this new variable into the regression.

Is this a good approach? Should I go back and modify the original `n1` field?

`EDIT`
I would prefer not to remove all entries where `n1` is 0, since there is a large number of them.

Comment: Can you just remove all training data for cases where $n_1 = 0$? If not, why not?

Comment: @DavidK - There is a large number of training data entries where `n1` is 0, so I'd prefer not to filter them out as I'd expect to see a lot of 0s  in the test data too. Is there a better way than to filter them out?